# Replying to a refusal of an invitation

Tags: expressions, invitation

By now, it's pretty simple to find different ways of refusing invitations in Japanese. However, what I can't really seem to find is a **reply to a refusal**. Something like *I'm sorry you can't make it*, *I hope you can join me next time* or even a simple *That sucks, man.*

So, what would be an appropriate reply to somebody's ちょっと用事があるんですけど (or whatever)? The only thing I could come up with my limited Japanese skills is something like 残念ですね but that seems a bit bland.

I'd be interested in both a casual version and a more formal one.

Answer (score 2):

**Informal**:

・あっちゃー。

・あっちゃー、そりゃ残念{ざんねん}。

・あ、そうなんだぁ。じゃあしょうがないね。

・えーマジ（で）？じゃあまた今度{こんど}ね！

I could go on all night..

**Formal**:

・そうですか、それは残念です。ではまたの機会{きかい}に。

・左様｛さよう｝でしたか。では仕方｛しかた｝がありませんね。またお誘｛さそ｝いします！

・そうでしたかぁ。それは残念ですねぇ。では、また次回{じかい}ということで。

Somebody stop me by force!

Comment: 「あっちゃー」って関東弁？結構新しい言葉？男の人が使う？（なにからきてるんだろう・・）

Comment: @Shoko 関東かもしれん。特別新しくないんちゃう？男性語やろな、主に。なにからきてるか、さっぱりわからん。

Answer (score 0):

more casual: そっかぁ。

more formal: ご都合も考えず申し訳ありません。お気になさらないでください。